# linux <termios.h> echo and it's means

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, termios

the status of the echo bit in the driver for file descriptor 0. Use redirection operator < to attach standard input to other files of devices. Try these experiments:

```
$ ./echostate < /dev/pts/0 
$ ./echostate < /etc/passwd
```

Output

[image]

plz explain to me the output produced by each of these commands.
i don't know these output difference.

### echostate.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
    struct termios info;
    int rv;
    rv = tcgetattr(0, &info);

    if (rv == -1) {
       perror("tcgetattr");
       exit(1);
    }
    if (info.c_lflag & ECHO)
        printf("echo is on, since its bit is 1\n");  
    else
        printf("echo if OFF, since its bit is 0\n"); 
}
```

Comment: Please also don't add text output as screenshot. Just copy&paste the text and add it to your question. After all it is text, no artwork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tcgetattr` doesn't make sense on a file (`/etc/passed`), but only on certain types of devices.

That's what the error message is telling you.